# Python schedule run with inconsistence

Tags: python, schedule

I've a main function with some code and i need run this every a predetermined time, but independent of the time that i configure it run every 2-3 minutes. I don't have an idea what's going. I'm show some example below.

```py
import schedule

def main():
    print('Some code here...')
    schedule.run_pending()

# the function main should be run every 30min...?
schedule.every(30).minutes.do(main)
schedule.every().hour.do(main)

main()
```

For what i researched this code shoud run every 30 minutes, but it run every 2-3 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not call your scheduled function directly. In your desired scenario, the function should run every X minutes - Meaning that the script that is responsible for running it, should run all the time, deciding when to invoke the function. a `while True` should do.

```py
import schedule

def main():
    print('Some code here...')

# the function main should be run every 30min...?
schedule.every(30).minutes.do(main)
schedule.every().hour.do(main)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
```